# Excel: Ctrl+Shift+F does nothing

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2013

I have Excel 2013 running on Windows 7 and am having difficulty with an often used shortcut. Ctrl+Shift+F, which normally shows the format cells dialog, does not work. Instead, it makes the cell's font size larger. How should I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for any third party apps, for example Veodin's Key Rocket. Their paid version uses Ctrl+Shift+F to increase font size. Out of the box, Excel will open the Format Cell dialog to the font tab with that shortcut.

Comment: It was a FactSet COM add-in. Thank's for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If you can't change the add-in behaviour, Excel has another keyboard shortcut for the Format Cells dialog: Ctrl+1